# SQL query to make a list and more

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, select

Below is a table with data inserted.

```
CREATE TABLE police(event_id VARCHAR(100), search_type VARCHAR(1000),
                    reported_by VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO police VALUES ('gng67g6yf', 'person','ceridigion' );
INSERT INTO police VALUES ('bfewbqfjhfb', 'person', 'ceridigion' );
INSERT INTO police VALUES ('ytftdfctg', 'n/a','ceridigion'  );
INSERT INTO police VALUES ('yufvugyu', 'person','pembrokeshire',  );
```

What I am trying to find out is a query which will list reported_by and have the searches that took place in the areas as well. Something like this below:

```
reported_by     Stopped and searched
ceridigion              2
pembrokeshire           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT reported_by,
       SUM(CASE WHEN search_type = 'person' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Stopped and searched`
FROM police
GROUP BY reported_by
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just need to count the number of rows (per `reported_by` that have a `search_type` that isn't `n/a`:

```
SELECT   reported_by, COUNT(*) AS "Stopped and searched"
FROM     police
WHERE    search_type != 'n/a'
GROUP BY reported_by
```